# upgrade to xcode 7.3 closures reference dont work

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

Previously (Xcode 7.2.1) had the following working code:

`let AQInputCallback: AudioQueueInputCallback = {(inUserData :UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>, inQueue :AudioQueueRef, inBuffer :AudioQueueBufferRef, inStartTime :UnsafePointer<AudioTimeStamp>, inNumPackets :UInt32, inPacketDesc :UnsafePointer<AudioStreamPacketDescription>) -> () in`

and referenced this as:

```
error = AudioQueueNewInput(&recordFormat, AQInputCallback, &recorder, nil, nil, 0, &self.inputQueue)
```

After upgrading to Xcode 7.3 this code throws a:

> Command failed due to signal: Segmentation fault: 11

Any help would be greatly appreciated.